# PHP Dom Get Only first meta tag

Tags: php, parsing, dom, html-parsing

I'm a beginner programmer who is building an application that scrapes data and puts data into a database.

I am trying to scrape something that looks like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="image_url_1">
<meta property="og:image" content="image_url_2">
```

I want the first meta tag's content but not the second's content. Right now the value of $meta_og_image is the content of the second meta tag. Here's my php code:

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHTML($sites_html);

$meta_og_image = null; //reset
//Get all meta tags and loop through them.
foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $meta) {

  if($meta->getAttribute('property')=='og:image'){ 
    //Assign the value from content attribute to $meta_og_image
    $meta_og_image = $meta->getAttribute('content');
  }
}
echo $meta_og_image;
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: I highly recommend this library (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) for html scraping. I started with DOM too as i was beginner, believe me simple_html_dom is much mush easier and better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can break the loop after you find the first one.

```
foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $meta) {
    if($meta->getAttribute('property') == 'og:image') { 
        //Assign the value from content attribute to $meta_og_image
        $meta_og_image = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        //stop all iterations in this loop
        break;
    }
}
```

This however is not very versatile if you plan on defining other variables in that loop. With that said you can check if `$meta_og_image` is already defined.

```
foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $meta) {
    if($meta->getAttribute('property') == 'og:image' && !isset($meta_og_image)) { 
        //Assign the value from content attribute to $meta_og_image
        $meta_og_image = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    }
}
```

You would have to remove the definition of `$meta_og_image` at the beginning. Later on if you check for it to be `null`, just use `!isset($meta_og_image)` instead.